# Hypothesis Testing for the Time-Invariance of the Mean

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, stationarity

I have a time series $X_t \in \{0, 1\} \forall t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

How do I investigate whether the mean of this time series belongs to the same distribution over time (weak stationarity!?)? Are there any standard statistical significance tests?

Comment: Stationarity is primarily a *modeling decision* rather than a fact about the world.  Wouldn't it be more useful to *analyze the nature* of temporal variation rather than try to make a decisive, yes/no determination?  To that end, plotting a smooth of the time series ought to be revealing.

Comment: @whuber let's say I plot a rolling average of the time series. Is there a way to determine normalcy of the behavior? For instance if the rolling window is large enough, and the average is 'too' noisy, we might say the feature is unstable across time.